# Unity Firebase works on the UnityEditor but it doesn't work when built to Android

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I made a simple unity firebase project that basicallychecks if the user has previously logged in if yes it loads the App scene if not it loads the Login one, both works on the editor. but it  doesnt work when built in Android, ive been trying to fix this in from 4 days now reading the docs and im not finding anything :(

I expected everything to work on Android Like in Unity Editor

Comment: Question is too broad

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
- Error message
- Version
- Simple code or steps to reproduce a problem are best